# Redirecting from win forms to web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to redirecting from win forms to web forms ?

Comment: The question and title are confussing, maybe if someone corrects the grammar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("pagelink")

Answer (score 2):

[Here's my source.](http://www.mystalia.net/2008/06/opening-a-webpage-in-the-default-browser-c-net/comment-page-1/)

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```